# Error : React.createElement: type is invalid : but got: undefined., Element type is invalid: but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am getting this error:

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> Check the render method of `EditContainer`.

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> Check the render method of `EditContainer`.

Edit.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
//styles
import styleArticle from '../../Styles/Article.css';
import styleTag from '../../Styles/tag.css'
//action
import * as ActionArticle from '../../Data/Article/action';
import * as ActionMedia from '../../Data/Media/action';
//util
import * as parseUrlParameter from '../../Lib/Utils/parseUrlParameter';
import { WithContext as ReactTags } from 'react-tag-input';


class EditContainer extends React.Component {

   ...

render() {
        const { tags } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className={styleArticle.articleContainer}>
                <ul className={styleArticle.articleContent}>
                    {/* image */}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title1}>이미지 업로드 (png, jpg)</div>
                        <div htmlFor={'upload'} className={styleArticle.uploadBox}>
                            {!this.state.imagePreview || this.state.imagePreview === '' ?
                                <div className={styleArticle.uploadImage} />
                            :
                                <img className={styleArticle.preview} src={this.state.imagePreview} />
                            }

                            <label className={styleArticle.uploadLabel} htmlFor={'upload'} />
                            <input className={styleArticle.upload} onChange={(e) => this.handleFileChange(e)}
                                   disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                                   type={'file'} id={'upload'} accept={'image/*'}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.uploadInputBox}>
                            <input className={styleArticle.uploadInput} type={'text'} placeholder={'이미지 이름'}
                                   disabled={true} value={this.state.imagename} />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/* image sub */}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title1}>GIF 이미지 업로드 (gif)</div>
                        <div htmlFor={'upload'} className={styleArticle.uploadBox}>
                            {!this.state.imagePreview1 || this.state.imagePreview1 === '' ?
                                <div className={styleArticle.uploadImage} />
                                :
                                <img className={styleArticle.preview} src={this.state.imagePreview1} />
                            }
                            <label className={styleArticle.uploadLabel} htmlFor={'upload1'} />
                            <input className={styleArticle.upload} onChange={(e) => this.handleSubFileChange(e)}
                                   disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                                   type={'file'} id={'upload1'} accept={'image/*'}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.uploadInputBox}>
                            <input className={styleArticle.uploadInput} type={'text'} placeholder={'이미지 이름'}
                                   disabled={true} value={this.state.imagename1} />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/* color */}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>배경색</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <input className={styleArticle.inputS}
                                type={'color'}
                                   value={this.state.bgcolor}
                                   onChange={(e) => this.setState({bgcolor: e.target.value})}
                                   disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/* tags */}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>키워드</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <ReactTags
                                tags={tags}
                                handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
                                handleAddition={this.handleAddition}
                                handleTagClick={this.handleTagClick}
                                placeholder={'키워드를 입력해주세요.'}
                                classNames={{
                                    tags: styleTag.tagsClass,
                                    tagInput: styleTag.tagInputClass,
                                    tagInputField: styleTag.tagInputFieldClass,
                                    selected: styleTag.selectedClass,
                                    tag: styleTag.tagClass,
                                    remove: styleTag.removeClass,
                                    suggestions: styleTag.suggestionsClass,
                                    activeSuggestion: styleTag.activeSuggestionClass
                                }}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*modifiedDate*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>날짜</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <input  className={styleArticle.inputS}
                                    value={this.state.modifiedDate}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({modifiedDate: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                                    placeholder={'입력폼: YYYY.MM.DD'}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*writer*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>Words By</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <input  className={styleArticle.inputS}
                                    value={this.state.writer}
                                   onChange={(e) => this.setState({writer: e.target.value})}
                                   type={'text'}
                                   disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*illustration*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>Illustration By</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <input  className={styleArticle.inputS}
                                    value={this.state.illustration}
                                   onChange={(e) => this.setState({illustration: e.target.value})}
                                   type={'text'}
                                   disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/* ref */}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>참고문헌</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.ref}
                                   onChange={(e) => this.setState({ref: e.target.value})} type={'text'}
                                   disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*search*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>검색</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.search}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({search: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*title*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>제목</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.title}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({title: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*abstract*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>본문</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.abstract}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({abstract: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*point1*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>소제목1</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.point1}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({point1: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*content1*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>단락1</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.content1}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({content1: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*point2*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>소제목2</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.point2}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({point2: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*content2*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>단락2</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.content2}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({content2: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*point3*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>소제목3</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.point3}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({point3: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*content3*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>단락3</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.content3}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({content3: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*point4*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>소제목4</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.point4}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({point4: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*content4*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>단락4</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.content4}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({content4: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*point5*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>소제목5</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.point5}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({point5: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*content5*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>단락5</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.content5}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({content5: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*point6*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>소제목6</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.point6}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({point6: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*content6*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>단락6</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.content6}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({content6: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*point7*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>소제목7</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.point7}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({point7: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*content7*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>단락7</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.content7}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({content7: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*point8*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>소제목8</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.point8}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({point8: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*content8*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>단락8</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.content8}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({content8: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*point9*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>소제목9</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.point9}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({point9: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*content9*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>단락9</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.content9}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({content9: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*point10*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>소제목10</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.point10}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({point10: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*content10*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>단락10</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.content10}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({content10: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*point11*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>소제목11</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.point11}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({point11: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*content11*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>단락11</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.content11}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({content11: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*point12*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>소제목12</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.point12}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({point12: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*content12*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>단락12</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.content12}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({content12: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*point13*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>소제목13</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.point13}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({point13: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*content13*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>단락13</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.content13}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({content13: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*point14*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>소제목14</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.point14}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({point14: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*content14*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>단락14</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.content14}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({content14: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*point15*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>소제목15</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.point15}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({point15: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {/*content15*/}
                    <li>
                        <div className={styleArticle.title}>단락15</div>
                        <div className={styleArticle.body}>
                            <textarea value={this.state.content15}
                                      onChange={(e) => this.setState({content15: e.target.value})}
                                      disabled={this.state.pageUrlType === 3}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div className={styleArticle.btnBox}>
                    {this.state.pageUrlType === 1 ?
                        <div onClick={this.submit} className={styleArticle.btn40}>게시하기</div>
                    :
                        null
                    }
                    {this.state.pageUrlType === 2 ?
                        <div onClick={this.submit} className={styleArticle.btn40}>수정하기</div>
                        :
                        null
                    }
                    {this.state.pageUrlType === 3 ?
                        <div onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/admin/gi')} className={styleArticle.btn40}>목록으로</div>
                        :
                        null
                    }

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect((state) => {
    return {
        userAuth: state.data.auth.userAuth,
    };
})(withRouter(EditContainer));
```

and root.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
//style
import styleApp from '../Styles/App.css';

//component
import AccountComponent from '../Container/Account';
import SettingComponent from '../Container/Setting';
import HomeComponent from '../Container/Home';
import SWComponent from '../Container/SW';
import GIComponent from '../Container/GI';
import SBComponent from '../Container/SB';
import SSComponent from '../Container/SS';
import BannerComponent from '../Container/Banner'
import SideNaveComponent from '../Component/SideNav';
//action
import * as actionAccount from "../Data/Account/action";
import storage from '../Lib/Api/storage';
class RootView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showNav: false
        }
    }
    componentWillMount() {...
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {...
    }

    checkSession = (token) => {...
    }
    checkUrl = curProps => {...
    }
    handleUrl = curProps => {...
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styleApp.rootBox}>
                {this.state.showNav ?
                    <SideNaveComponent url={this.props.location.pathname} />
                :
                    <div className={styleApp.accountBox}>
                        <Route path={'/admin/signin'} exact={false} strict={false} component={AccountComponent} />
                    </div>
                }
                <div className={styleApp.contentBox}>
                    <Route path={'/admin/home'} exact={false} strict={false} component={HomeComponent} />
                    <Route path={'/admin/sw'} exact={false} strict={false} component={SWComponent} />
                    <Route path={'/admin/gi'} exact={false} strict={false} component={GIComponent} />
                    <Route path={'/admin/ss'} exact={false} strict={false} component={SSComponent} />
                    <Route path={'/admin/sb'} exact={false} strict={false} component={SBComponent} />
                    <Route path={'/admin/banner'} exact={false} strict={false} component={BannerComponent} />
                    <Route path={'/admin/setting'} exact={false} strict={false} component={SettingComponent} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect((state) => {
    return {
        userAuth: state.data.auth.userAuth,
    };
})(withRouter(RootView));
```

I searched and found many solutions and solved cases. But i don't think it's goona work for my case. I guess export is written properly and also the name 'EditContainer' too..
What are the recommended solutions in this case?

Comment: The error message says "Check the render method of EditContainer.", so maybe you could show us the render method of EditContainer?

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie I revised this post. Did I post it correctly as you suggested? I deleted other contents and attached them because the render() fo EditContainer in edit.jsx is so long